# Regular Expression to match a link but with the exception of a certain type of links

Tags: java, regex, http, regex-greedy

Problem: I am trying to match a link and replace it with an empty string. To add to that I do not want to match links with `.png`, only all other links.

So far I have come up with:

```
(https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*
```

But when I have added negative look behind for `.png` I have not been successful.

So basically *what might be the correct regular expression to match a http link but not match http link with `.png`?*

I would prefer a greedy approach.

Please find the expected input/output below

**Expected Results**

**The Text Input 1:**

```
    <img id="segmentForm:wfib" style="border: 0px;"            
    src="http://localhost:8080/example/emg/WidgetFillInTheBlankRed.com" alt=""    />
    <img src="../../img/WidgetFillInTheBlankGreen.png" alt="POB1" />
```

**The Text Output 1 [Not Same as Input, Link Matched and Replaced with Empty String]**

```
    <img id="segmentForm:wfib" style="border: 0px;" src="" alt="" />
    <img src="../../img/WidgetFillInTheBlankGreen.png" alt="POB1" />
```

**The Text Input 2:**

```
    <img id="segmentForm:wfib" style="border: 0px;"         

    src="http://localhost:8080/example/emg/WidgetFillInTheBlankRed.png" alt="" />
    <img src="../../img/WidgetFillInTheBlankGreen.png" alt="FIB1" />
```

**The Text Output 2 [Same as Input]**

```
    <img id="segmentForm:wfib" style="border: 0px;"     

    src="http://localhost:8080/example/emg/WidgetFillInTheBlankRed.png" alt="" />
    <img src="../../img/WidgetFillInTheBlankGreen.png" alt="FIB1" />
```

Comment: Is http://i.imgur.com/w6RfaJo.png a PNG link?

Comment: A link can be                src="http://localhost:8080/example/emg/WidgetFillInTheBlankRed.png"

Comment: What about links in form of text like `<div>http://server/page.html</div>`, should it also be found?

Comment: Yes, it should be found, or it should be matched.

Comment: I think you should see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/460557

Answer (score 2):

```
(https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((\/\/)|(\\))+[\w\d:#@%\/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*(?<!png)$
```

Tested using https://regex101.com/

```
http://server/page.com -> 1 Match
http://server/page.png -> No Match
```

Comment: When I test with (https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*(?<!png)$ all links are getting accepted. When I remove the $ then I get src="g". Can you test with the whole text that I have provided in the question.

Comment: Basically it is not really working when I input https://localhost:8080/example/ex/Just.png I get just "g"

Comment: Just to add on to this, I see that your solution works in regex101. I see in the debugger it is backtracking for not having png. The same solution is not working in Java, do you think java library behave differently for negative lookbehind?